# Cron: every 44th day of the year

Tags: cron

How to compose a cron string for each some day number of year, for instance, each 44th day or each 256th day of year?

`0 0 44 * *` doesn't work

Comment: try `0 0 */44 * *`

Comment: From the cron tag: Questions about configuring cron for systems or administration are OFF TOPIC.